# how do i implement this algebraic sum in R?

Tags: r, sum, algebra

I have now been trying different solutions and ways for a long time. Could somebody please help me understand how i could implement this sum calculation in R?

I also want save the result of that calculation to a vector called `sumOne`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i <- 10:109

sum(i^3 + 4*i^2)

[1] 37687400
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use vectorized option in `R`

```
sum(v1^3 + 4 * v1^2)
[1] 37687400
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- 10:109
```